Evil-mode doesn't work on Emacs 29.1 (Windows)
I recently installed emacs 29.1 on my Windows machine from this repo:
https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/emacs/windows/emacs-29/
I started configuring it and the first thing I did is install evil-mode, so I can have nice Vim keybindings.
I installed it with ELPA, and the installation seemed to work without any issues. The error shows up when I try to use the evil-mode package, with:
M-x evil-mode

, or with:
(require 'evil)
(evil-mode 1)

directly in my config file.
This is the error Emacs prompts me:
Warning (comp): evil-vars.el:561:25: Warning: the function `evil-delete-backward-word' is not known to be defined.

This seems to be an error from the evil package source code, as it is referring to the file evil-vars.el which can be found in the following directory:
~/.emacs.d/elpa/evil-20240716.1100
This is the block of code it is referring to:
;; File: evil-vars.el
;; Starts at line 538
(defcustom evil-want-C-w-delete t
  "Whether `C-w' deletes a word in Insert/Ex/Search state."
  :type 'boolean
  :group 'evil
  :set (lambda (sym value)
         (set-default sym value)
         (when (and (boundp 'evil-insert-state-map)
                    (boundp 'evil-replace-state-map))
           (cond
            ((and (not value)
                  (eq (lookup-key evil-insert-state-map (kbd "C-w"))
                      'evil-delete-backward-word))
             (define-key evil-insert-state-map (kbd "C-w") 'evil-window-map)
             (define-key evil-replace-state-map (kbd "C-w") 'evil-window-map))
            ((and value
                  (eq (lookup-key evil-insert-state-map (kbd "C-w"))
                      'evil-window-map))
             (define-key evil-insert-state-map (kbd "C-w") 'evil-delete-backward-word)
             (define-key evil-replace-state-map (kbd "C-w") 'evil-delete-backward-word))))
         (when (boundp 'evil-command-line-map)
           (cond
            ((and (not value)
                  (eq (lookup-key evil-command-line-map (kbd "C-w"))
                      ;; --> Here is the referred error, at line 561 <--
                      #'evil-delete-backward-word))
             (define-key evil-command-line-map (kbd "C-w") nil))
            ((and value
                  (null (lookup-key evil-command-line-map (kbd "C-w"))))
             (define-key evil-command-line-map (kbd "C-w") #'evil-delete-backward-word))))
         (when (boundp 'evil-ex-search-keymap)
           (cond
            ((and (not value)
                  (null (lookup-key evil-ex-search-keymap (kbd "C-w"))))
             (define-key evil-ex-search-keymap (kbd "C-w") 'evil-search-yank-word))
            ((and value
                  (eq (lookup-key evil-ex-search-keymap (kbd "C-w"))
                      'evil-search-yank-word))
             (define-key evil-ex-search-keymap (kbd "C-w") nil))))))

The funny thing is, I don't get the same error with Emacs 27. But I don't want to have to downgrade in order for this to work.

Have you tried using Evil? The above message you get is not an error but a warning. You can probably just ignore that warning.
Emacs 27 and 29 do things slightly differently, so it is not surprising to get different warnings.

Yes, I tried using it with:
M-x evil-mode
and also with:
(require 'evil)
(evil-mode 1)
in my config file (as I mentioned in the post).
I understand now the warning it's not what is causing the error, but nonetheless, I can't use Evil.

M-x evil-mode and using it works fine here, in a custom compiled Emacs from recent master branch. That is probably something in your setup that errors and makes Emacs abort loading your init file before evil is loaded. Try running Emacs with --debug-init option and see if you get a good stack trace, or try to bisect your init file.  Perhaps this SX answer is of interest too.

It's just a compilation warning, so you can ignore it
